# Flutter `1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.`

Tags: flutter, dart

I've downloaded project from github and this is the error, ***1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.***

This is my main.dart

```
class GameWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final FlutterBirdGame flutterBirdGame;
  GameWrapper(this.flutterBirdGame);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return flutterBirdGame.widget;
  }
}

class Singleton {
  Size screenSize;
  Singleton._privateConstructor();
  static final Singleton instance = Singleton._privateConstructor();
}

void main() async {
  // initial settings
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Flame.audio.disableLog();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

  var sprite = await Flame.images.loadAll(["sprite.png"]);
  var screenSize = await Flame.util.initialDimensions();
  Singleton.instance.screenSize = screenSize;
  var flutterBirdGame = FlutterBirdGame(sprite[0], screenSize);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'myfirstgame',
    home: GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails evt) => flutterBirdGame.onTap(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: GameWrapper(flutterBirdGame),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

widget_test.dart i am getting error from this line, its say Try adding the missing arguments.dart(not_enough_positional_arguments) but i dont know how to pass argument.

```
await tester.pumpWidget(GameWrapper()); //
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GameWrapper` class needs `FlutterBirdGame` instance in it's constructor, try to add it:

```dart
final birdGame = // init FlutterBirdGame variable
await tester.pumpWidget(GameWrapper(birdGame));
```

Comment: final birdGame = // init FlutterBirdGame variable, what does it mean?

Comment: You are initialized `GameWrapper` in `main` function. You can use the similar instance or mock in (more [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking)).

Comment: It should be a valid `FlutterBirdGame` initialization.

Comment: how? please tell me sir

Comment: In `main` function` you are declared it: `var flutterBirdGame = FlutterBirdGame(sprite[0], screenSize);`.

Comment: `final FlutterBirdGame flutterBirdGame;` should i declared like this in widget_test.dart?

Comment: Yes, but you can use Mock object for it. Read more about how to wrap real object to test object [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking).

Answer (score 0):

Your `GameWrapper` class requires `FlutterBirdGame` object :
Try to do like this :

```
final flutterBirdGame = new FlutterBirdGame();
await tester.pumpWidget(GameWrapper(flutterBirdGame));
```

Comment: `final flutterBirdGame = new FlutterBirdGame();` in this line i have error 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.

Comment: As mentioned in the link [https://github.com/g0rdan/Flutter.Bird/blob/master/lib/game/game.dart][1]

constructor of FlutterBirdGame class has 2 required fields : 

> FlutterBirdGame(Image spriteImage, Size screenSize) {...}

so you are required to pass those objects.


  [1]: https://github.com/g0rdan/Flutter.Bird/blob/master/lib/game/game.dart

Comment: how ? please tell me isr